# How do I enable Firefox check spelling on single line text-boxes forever?

Tags: firefox, spell-check

As you know, we can enable the spell checker on single line text boxes in the following way:

[image]

We have to enable it every time for checking words.

How can we enable it forever, so it doesn't need to be enabled each time?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To [change how Firefox checks spelling](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Layout.spellcheckDefault)  and enable spell-checking on one-line and multi-line text fields, use **about:config** to set `layout.spellcheckDefault`  to `2`.

[To edit your configuration](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config), type `about:config` in the address bar and press Enter.

[Reference](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Layout.spellcheckDefault#2)

Comment: What does "2" mean? What is the effect?

Comment: *[Is there a way to have Firefox's spellcheck check the spelling in all text input fields?](https://superuser.com/questions/599284/is-there-a-way-to-have-firefoxs-spellcheck-check-the-spelling-in-all-text-input/599303#599303)* has an explanation.