# Is there a way to have Firefox's spellcheck check the spelling in all text input fields?

Tags: firefox, spell-check

[Apparently](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-do-i-use-firefox-spell-checker) "Firefox automatically checks the spelling of words that you enter in text boxes", but is there a way to have it check other texted based fields, such as `<input type="text" />`?

Answer (score 3):

Type **about:config** in the address bar, agree to the warning if displayed, then set the value of [**layout.spellcheckDefault**](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Layout.spellcheckDefault) to **2**.

> 0: Disable spellchecker.
>
> 1: Enable spellchecker for multi-line controls (e.g., <textarea>s). (Default in Firefox and SeaMonkey)
>
> 2: Enable spellchecker for multi-line controls and single-line controls. (Default in Camino)